# Category name as page title

Tags: categories, title, breadcrumb

I'm using a theme from Envato Market (Painting). What I need to do is to replace a generic page title which is displayed when I open a category page from Shop or Portfolio, with the actual name of the category. The developer of the theme said that I can’t dynamically display the title. But in the same time I see that the breadcrumbs shows the correct title of the category. Could the page title be grabbed from the breadcrumbs and displayed? Or maybe there is another solution. Can someone help me and explain it for a noob? Thank you!

Comment: You can use plugins for it. For example https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ to update archive templates title with custom.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but after seeing the plugin's page I realized that I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code in the theme files to do this. Open the file `category.php` (if this file doesn't exist, try `archive.php`) and replace the text you want to change with `single_cat_title()`

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/)

**However these changes will be overwritten if you update your theme**

You can create a child theme or use plugins to get around this.

Comment: Don't change theme templates if you want to update your theme in future. Create child theme or write your plugin better

Comment: Great, is working, but now I need to add some style to it. Can you tell me how? Remember, I'm a complete noob in php.

Comment: My lines looks like this: elseif( is_tax() ):
 $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
 $title = esc_html__(single_cat_title($prefix = '', $display = true),'painting');
 painting_custom_subtitle_section( $title );    It's correct?

Comment: You can do this a number of ways. Since you are a beginner, the easiest, is to wrap your call with some inline style. Change your call to single_cat_title() to '<span style="[whatever style rules here]">' . single_cat_title() . '</span>'

Comment: Also it is customary to check my answer as correct since I did solve your original question. Thank you

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, it's my first time here.

Comment: No problem! It takes some getting used to but this place is one of the best resources in the world for learning.

Comment: Got it to work!!! The solution is adding instead the generic title single_cat_title('', false). Thank you a thousand times Jeremy!

Comment: No problem, just remember to keep a backup of the file somewhere. If you update your theme on accident, you can use the backup to quickly put it back.